# Is it possible to get list of all id's that are grouped by

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

WE have a springboot application and there a scenario where we are using native query to insert data into a table based on the groupby query on another table. Now, I need to get the list of all the id's of the records that are grouped by before insert.

Query:

```
insert into table2 (column1,column2) 
select column1,column2 
from table1 
group by column1,column2
```

Now, I need to get the list of id's that are grouped in table1. Is  it possible?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I don't understand this question. If table1 has an ID and a column1 and a column2 and maybe more columns, and you select all rows (no where clause) and group the rows by column1 and columns2, then still all rows got involved in the aggregation. Every ID is part of one of the groups. So the "list of ids that are grouped in table1" is list of IDs in table1: `select id from table1`. Or what else do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using native query, does a grouping at SQL level like below solve your problem? (below is MYSQL code)

```
select column1,column2, group_concat(id_column) 
from table1
group by column1,column2
```

Comment: Thanks , it works for me group_concat(id_column)

Comment: Worth noting that the result length of the [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function is limited to 1024 bytes by default, in case your have a lot of ids grouped it can be a problem because the result will  be cuted, so you must use [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) command to increase the default value

Answer (score 0):

With only access to table 2 you cannot get the ids what were grouped in table1, unless column1 or column2 is the id itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where we have a marker in the users table to know whether the id's have been summarised. The function returns the list of id's to summarise, inserts the information into the table summary and marks the id's as inserted.
This does not account for find more users created in a month already summarised (it will create a second row for the same month). It could be modified to update if the month+year is found, but it demonstrates what I understand you are trying to achieve.

> ```
> create table users (
> id int,
> created date,
> summarised int default 0);
> insert into users (id, created)values
> (1,'2020-01-01'),
> (2,'2020-01-15'),
> (3,'2020-02-15');
> create table summary(
> year int,
> month int,
> num_id int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

3 rows affected

> ✓

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION Summarise()
>     RETURNS TABLE (ID int)
>     LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
>   $BODY$
>       BEGIN
>            RETURN QUERY
>               SELECT users.id from users where summarised = 0;
>  
>         insert into summary
>            select 
>                 date_part('year',users.created),
>                 date_part('month',users.created)
>                 ,count(users.id)
>            from users 
>            where users.summarised = 0
>            group by date_part('year',users.created), date_part('month',users.created);
>            
>            
>         UPDATE users set summarised = 1;
>       END;
>   $BODY$
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from users;
> select * from summary;
> select Summarise();
> select * from users;
> select * from summary;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | created    | summarised
> -: | :--------- | ---------:
>  1 | 2020-01-01 |          0
>  2 | 2020-01-15 |          0
>  3 | 2020-02-15 |          0
>
> year | month | num_id
> ---: | ----: | -----:
>
> | summarise |
> | --------: |
> |         1 |
> |         2 |
> |         3 |
>
> id | created    | summarised
> -: | :--------- | ---------:
>  1 | 2020-01-01 |          1
>  2 | 2020-01-15 |          1
>  3 | 2020-02-15 |          1
>
> year | month | num_id
> ---: | ----: | -----:
> 2020 |     1 |      2
> 2020 |     2 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bb4c4690591faa873b03367876067b60)*

Comment: I dont want the ids to be stored in the table but need to return the ids once the query is completed

Comment: BEGIN
           RETURN QUERY
              SELECT users.id from users where summarised = 0;
 
        insert into summary
           select 
                date_part('year',users.created),
                date_part('month',users.created)
                ,count(users.id)
           from users 
           where users.summarised = 0
           group by date_part('year',users.created), date_part('month',users.created); Does this code scan the table twice or only once?

Comment: We're running 3 queries: select, select-insert and update. If there are 1000 rows you wont have time for a coffee,  if there are a million it's going to be slow.